# SwiftUI multiple NavigationView

Tags: swiftui-navigationview

Hello I am new to SwiftUI,

I have two navigationStack one is in parent and one is in childview,
now i have to use parent navigationStack from child but if i is use navigationlink in child view it refers to child's  navigation view,

**For example
RootView1, RootView2**

RootView1 has navigationStack and it navigate to ChildView.
ChildView has navigationStack for its sub views
now i want to navigate to RootView2 from ChildView

If i use navigationLink in ChildView it refers to ChildView's navigationview instead i want to call parent's navigation view

How can i achieve this?

Multiple NavigationView/NavigationStack hierarchy in SwiftUI

Comment: Most apps only need 1 NavigationView. There are a few exceptions but this doesn’t sound like one of them.

Comment: @loremipsum, yes i agree with you but in my case I have first parent view->chileview (with navigation stack) ->subchildview
Now i want to open second parent view from sub child view and for that i want to access  first parent view's navigation stack

Comment: You only need 1 NavigationView/Stack. TabView/sheet’s are exceptions